# AngularJS: Outputting HTML returned from controller showing HTML code

Tags: angularjs

I have a status field and would like to display an icon rather than the value in the db. Ultimately this will be in an ng-repeat of table rows. I coded an scope function to return the icon (colored as needed) when based the $scope value but it is showing the actual HTML code not the icon. I tried the Handlebar's trick of using 3 curly braces but Angular would have none of that.

How can I return the icon rather than the HTML or is there a better way for Angular to accomplish "dynamic" icons.

Here's my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope){

  $scope.getStatus = function(val){
    switch(val){
    case 'I':
      return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" tooltip="In_Progress" style="color: #000099;"></span>';
      break;
    case 'R':
      return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" tooltip="Recommended"></span>';
      break;
    case 'A':
      return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" tooltip="Approved" style="color: #009900;"></span>';
      break;
    case 'D':
      return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" tooltip="Denied" style="color: #990000;"></span>';
      break;
    case 'W':
      return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" tooltip="Withdrawn" style="color: #E0A02D;"></span>';
      break;
    case 'P':
      return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" tooltip="Paid" style="color: #009900;"></span>';
      break;
    }
  };

}); // end MainController
```

and my HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <table style="width:50%; margin:0 auto;">
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            {{ getStatus("I") }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I also have a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BqkbLP?p=preview) but plunker doesn't really do glyphicons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to change your binding from the default binding to an html binding to avoid it from being escaped.

From:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
<table style="width:50%; margin:0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
        {{ getStatus("I") }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

to:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
<table style="width:50%; margin:0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;" ng-bind-html="getStatus('I')"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

See [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

You also need to add ngSanitize in your html:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

And in your application requirements:

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngSanitize']);
```

Comment: Just edited my first answer to add the missing code.